# Duplicating the sound source

Tags: pressure, acoustics

I've been struggling to find an answer to this question since I get a different answer at every other website I read.

Suppose I have a sound source, which for example has a SPL of 60dB SPL.
Now, If I duplicate my sound source and place it next to the original one, then which of following parameters do actually gets doubled? The sound pressure or the sound intensity?

Both answers result in a different increase of dB SPL since intensity is proportional to the square of the sound pressure.

Answer (score 0):

If your sources are incoherent radiating sources, the sound pressures add, as shown by the equation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Multiple_sources)

$$L_\Sigma = 10 \log_{10}[10^{\frac{L_0}{10dB}} + 10^{\frac{L_1}{10dB}} + 10^{\frac{L_2}{10dB}} + \dots ] dB$$

If you convert out of the decibel scales, it's clear that the pressures are adding.

If your sources are coherent, the story may change.  Obviously if you consider two halves of a speaker, the total intensity (a measure of power/area) must be additive intuitively, because you're putting so many watts of power into your speaker in the first place.  As you do so, you're going to see all sorts of coupling effects which will lead the pressures to behave differently than they did in the incoherent case.

Answer (score 0):

If the two sound sources emit coherent sound waves, then the sound pressures would double. If the sound emitted of the sources is incoherent, then the sound intensity would double.